Module script variable returning as nil
Hi I have a module script with a variable "Worker" inside of it that starts out as nil, but when I set the player to it(worker = player) it doesn't change. 'Cause when I print it it says nil
ModuleScript:
local workModule = {
    ["Worker"] = nil
}

return workModule

Set script:
local button = script.Parent
local house = workspace.House
local moduleTable = require(workspace.Part.ModuleScript)
local remoteEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent
local buttonModule = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.ButtonModule)
local workersGUI = game.ReplicatedStorage.WorkersGUI

button.Touched:Connect(function(plr)
    if (plr.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")) then
        local player = plr.Parent
        
        moduleTable.Worker = player
        workersGUI:FireAllClients()
        
        buttonModule.SwitchOn(button)
        buttonModule.Player = player
    end
end)


I tried to look at my other code as an example of setting a modulescript variable to the player but it didn't help. I don't know why it works for other modulescripts but not this one

What is the error you are getting?

Are you trying to make it so that other players can see what player's character model is stored in the ModuleScript?

@RyanLuu no error, just a problem and that problem is that moduleTable.Worker is staying as nil, even after I supposedly set it to player

You've shared the code that sets the value, but where is the code that prints it out?

This is not the intended use of ModuleScripts, you can't update variables inside of them and then access that variable from another script as far as I'm aware.
What you should do is store the Worker inside a StringValue if the Worker variable needs to be accessible from both the client side and the server side you can just store the StringValue inside the ReplicatedStorage, this will retain the same value on the server and replicate it to each client.
